# How do I access the sound device with modern libraries?

Tags: audio, alsa

It used to be that if you wanted to test your sound you could simply [cat any file to `/dev/snd`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Alsa-sound-6.html#ss6.3), but that doesn't appear to work on any of the systems (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, Arch) that I've tried.

From what I've read, this can be any kind of file - text, pdf, whatever. And if it's a .wav file then it will actually play music.

So how can you do the same thing on modern systems (e.g. ones using pulse audio & other drivers)

Answer (score 2):

From my testing, `aplay` works:

```
aplay <filename>
```

When I did

```
aplay test.html   # a simple html file
```

I got hissy static.

```
aplay something.wav
```

Played the music in the wav file. And in a bizarre twist, a file containing this:

```
Fri Jan 13 08:20:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:21:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:22:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:23:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:24:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:25:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:26:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:27:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:28:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:29:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:30:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:31:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:32:01 CST 2012
Fri Jan 13 08:33:01 CST 2012
```

Makes a gentle "beep"

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is specifically to pipe arbitrary data from a file to your sound card then your solution is solid.

If your goal is simply to test that your sound works then I would recommend the command `speaker-test`. It plays static over a single channel by default. On Debian based systems it comes from the `alsa-utils` package.